# It's posible to translate this R code into c#?

Tags: c#, r

```
# Vector: 
vc <- seq(1:10) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
vc[vc > 2 & vc < 8] <- 11 # 1 2 11 11 11 11 11 8 9 10
print(sum(vc[vc > 2 & vc < 8])) # 55
```

I have a vector from 1 to 10, then I want to replace the values of that vector that have a value greather than 2 and lower than 8 for 11. Then I want to sum all the values that match with that restriction, is there an equivalent on C#?

(It is a simplified example).

Thanks!

Comment: I think, it's possible. But you should try yourself first. And post question if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with LINQ:

```
var original = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
edited = original.Select(x => (x > 2 && x < 8) ? 11 : x).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", edited)); //outputs: 1 2 11 11 11 11 11 8 9 10 
int sum = original.Sum(x => (x > 2 && x < 8) ? 11 : 0);
Console.Write(sum); //outputs 55
```

Comment: You could use `Enumerable.Range(1, 10)` to create the sequence in the first place, probably a closer equivalent to a sequence function.

Comment: You are right, I seem to have skipped over that. Corrected my answer.